# How to see full logs on GitHub Actions (without restarting or cancelling workflow)?

Tags: github, github-actions

Suppose a CI workflow is running, how can I view the full logs?

[image]

#### What I've tried

- I can see the logs if I click on the task *immediately* after starting a new workflow, for example:

[image]

- But once a workflow has been running I cannot see the full logs
- I've tried clicking on the cog on top right of screen -> View raw logs, but it shows:

```
2022-07-14T16:29:41.4911629Z Requested labels: ubuntu-latest
2022-07-14T16:29:41.4911713Z Job defined at: username/repo/.github/workflows/main.yml@refs/heads/main
2022-07-14T16:29:41.4911751Z Waiting for a runner to pick up this job...
2022-07-14T16:29:42.2335026Z Job is waiting for a hosted runner to come online.
2022-07-14T16:29:48.5809023Z Job is about to start running on the hosted runner: Hosted Agent (hosted)
```

But I know there's much more than that.

- If I cancel the workflow, it suddenly shows the full logs (I just need to be able to see them without cancelling or restarting a workflow):

[image]

Comment: The logging experience of actions isn't exactly their strong point :)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but may help: there is a checkbox to enable more logging information than is provided by default. See [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/enabling-debug-logging).

Comment: Seems its coming around July 31st 2023 https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/886#issuecomment-1564345968

Answer (score 8):

This is a bug, and it's been brought up to their attention long time ago. Still no fix.

https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/2131

Comment: Looks like the various teams are playing pass-the-parcel with that issue and giving no external visibility on where the problem lies. Also see https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/886

Answer (score 3):

[Apparently](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/886) (which is linked from the issue Marko T mentions), the way the web front end (to Github Actions) works is that it uses a websocket to stream in log lines as they are produced, and issues GETs to bring in lines from terminated steps. The problem comes when a component has hung or is otherwise not producing a lot of output; you don't get the historical output of it until the step terminates (whether by completing, failing, or being cancelled) and there isn't much you can do about it. (Possible workaround *that I've not tested:* doing a full fetch of the log might work? It won't be pretty but at least you'll be able to see what's going on.)

It's a very frustrating usability issue to say the least, especially as it only really shows up when things are going nastily wrong. Apparently users are supposed to go [here](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/44250) to discuss it so that ["product managers and engineers will be able to review them"](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/886#issuecomment-997039117) but it looks more like a way of black-holing user requests in somewhere that isn't actually watched. I could be wrong and maligning people here, but it doesn't really have that great a look to me as an external user.