# Github Action Gradle unit tests not triggered

Tags: github, github-actions

Github Actions newbie here :).

The workflow file:

```
name: ga-poc-sb CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'temurin'

      - name: Validate Gradle wrapper
        uses: gradle/wrapper-validation-action@e6e38bacfdf1a337459f332974bb2327a31aaf4b

      - name: Build
        uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@67421db6bd0bf253fb4bd25b31ebb98943c375e1
        with:
          arguments: build

      - name: Test
        uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@67421db6bd0bf253fb4bd25b31ebb98943c375e1
        with:
          arguments: test
```

Till yesterday, I was able to see the workflow logs but now cannot, perhaps due to an [existing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72984253/how-to-see-full-logs-on-github-actions-without-restarting-or-cancelling-workflo) in the Github UI. Still, I recall some logs from yesterday, and they match with my local (act) logging as follows:

```
[ga-poc-sb CI/build]   ✅  Success - Main Build
[ga-poc-sb CI/build] ⭐ Run Main Test
[ga-poc-sb CI/build]     docker cp src=/Users/oj/.cache/act/gradle-gradle-build-action@67421db6bd0bf253fb4bd25b31ebb98943c375e1/ dst=/var/run/act/actions/gradle-gradle-build-action@67421db6bd0bf253fb4bd25b31ebb98943c375e1/
[ga-poc-sb CI/build]     docker exec cmd=[node /var/run/act/actions/gradle-gradle-build-action@67421db6bd0bf253fb4bd25b31ebb98943c375e1/dist/main/index.js] user= workdir=
[ga-poc-sb CI/build]     ::debug::Determined user.home from java -version output: '/root'
| Gradle setup only performed on first gradle-build-action step in workflow.
| [command]/Volumes/Development/work-directories/repositories/dev/ga-poc-sb/gradlew test
| > Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
| > Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
| > Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
| > Task :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
| > Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
| > Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
| > Task :test UP-TO-DATE
| 
| BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
| 4 actionable tasks: 4 up-to-date
[ga-poc-sb CI/build]   ✅  Success - Main Test
[ga-poc-sb CI/build] ⭐ Run Post Test
[ga-poc-sb CI/build]     docker exec cmd=[node /var/run/act/actions/gradle-gradle-build-action@67421db6bd0bf253fb4bd25b31ebb98943c375e1/dist/post/index.js] user= workdir=
| Gradle setup post-action only performed for first gradle-build-action step in workflow.
[ga-poc-sb CI/build]   ✅  Success - Post Test
[ga-poc-sb CI/build] ⭐ Run Post Build
[ga-poc-sb CI/build]     docker exec cmd=[node /var/run/act/actions/gradle-gradle-build-action@67421db6bd0bf253fb4bd25b31ebb98943c375e1/dist/post/index.js] user= workdir=
| Stopping all Gradle daemons
| Stopping Gradle daemons in /root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.6-bin/9l9tetv7ltxvx3i8an4pb86ye/gradle-7.6
| [command]/root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.6-bin/9l9tetv7ltxvx3i8an4pb86ye/gradle-7.6/bin/gradle --stop
| Stopping Daemon(s)
| 1 Daemon stopped
| In final post-action step, saving state and writing summary
| Cache is read-only: will not save state for use in subsequent builds.
[ga-poc-sb CI/build]   ✅  Success - Post Build
[ga-poc-sb CI/build] ⭐ Run Post Set up JDK 17
[ga-poc-sb CI/build]     docker exec cmd=[node /var/run/act/actions/actions-setup-java@v3/dist/cleanup/index.js] user= workdir=
[ga-poc-sb CI/build]   ✅  Success - Post Set up JDK 17
[ga-poc-sb CI/build]   Job succeeded
```

This caught my eye:

```
[ga-poc-sb CI/build]     docker exec cmd=[node /var/run/act/actions/gradle-gradle-build-action@67421db6bd0bf253fb4bd25b31ebb98943c375e1/dist/post/index.js] user= workdir=
| Gradle setup post-action only performed for first gradle-build-action step in workflow.
```

Question: Why aren't the unit tests triggered(I see the results when I do a normal Gradle test in my IntelliJ setup).

Do I need to add another job named 'Test'(which again installs Java, and clones repo) to trigger the unit tests?